# Conditionally hide button in cell of KendoUIGrid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid in which one column has a button, but I musgt hide the button depending on the row which the button is in (in this case first row and last row).

How can I do that?

My code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="grid">  
</div>

<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" },
        { width: 150, 
            command:            
                    [
                {
                    name:"Up",
                    imageClass: "k-icon k-i-arrow-s",
                    click: function(e) {
                        var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); 
                        var item = this.dataItem(tr);
                        var dir = "U";
                        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                        moveItem.moveUp(dir,dataItem.order).addCallback(function(response){
                        alert(response);
                        })
                    }
                },
          ]
            }
  ],
  dataSource: [
      { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ]
});
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.hideColumn(grid.columns[0].columns[0]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

==================

I have added the code that contains the moveItem.moveItemUp method.

In this method I use a remote procedure call to execute some server side javascript. It doesn't have anything to do, really, with hiding of the buttons.

```
<xe:jsonRpcService
        id="jsonRpcService1"
        serviceName="moveItem">
        <xe:this.methods>
            <xe:remoteMethod
                name="moveUp"
                script="return direction + order">
                <xe:this.arguments>
                    <xe:remoteMethodArg
                        name="direction"
                        type="string">
                    </xe:remoteMethodArg>
                    <xe:remoteMethodArg
                        name="order"
                        type="number">
                    </xe:remoteMethodArg>
                </xe:this.arguments>
            </xe:remoteMethod>
        </xe:this.methods>
    </xe:jsonRpcService>
```

Comment: Please share the method "moveItem.moveUp" code.

Comment: Do you only need to hide the button in the first and last row, or will the rows with the button to disable vary?

Comment: In this case I need the down button to be disabled on the first row and the up button on the last row.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to customise Kendo UI Grid row and cell appearance:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/style-rows-cells-based-on-data-item-values

Row and column templates do not provide information about the data item index, so the remaining option is to use the `dataBound` event, get the Grid [`tbody`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields-tbody), locate the first and last child table rows and finally, hide the buttons inside them. The buttons will have a `k-grid-Up` CSS class, i.e. depending on the command `name` (case sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

One way of hiding controls within the grid is via CSS. You could create the following styles to hide the first and last buttons in a row:

```
#grid> tbody > tr:first-child > td > input {
  display:none;
}

#grid> tbody > tr:last-child > td > input {
  display:none;
}
```

(You will need to change these styles to get it work with your specific grid and buttons).